# T-SQL date range in a table split and add the individual date to the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Thank you for looking to help. I have a table like this. Lets call it TableA

```
[Id] [CHAR](10) NOT NULL,
[DType] [SMALLINT] NOT NULL,
[PType] [CHAR](1) NOT NULL,
[Period] [INT] NOT NULL,
[FromDate] [SMALLDATETIME] NOT NULL,
[ToDate] [SMALLDATETIME] NOT NULL,
[Highval] [DECIMAL](19, 4) NULL,
```

The Primary Key is `Id, DType, PType, Period, FromDate`

There is data in it like this:

```
Id          DType   PType   Period  FromDate    ToDate      Highval
-------------------------------------------------------------------    
000000000G  1       A       2015    2014-11-02  2014-11-04  0.4800
000000000G  1       A       2015    2014-11-01  2014-11-01  1.2860
000000000G  1       A       2015    2014-10-28  2014-10-31  1.2290
000000000K  4       2       2015    2014-12-17  2014-12-20  2.5800
000000000K  4       3       2015    2014-12-15  2014-12-16  2.1700
000000000K  4       3       2015    2014-11-14  2014-12-14  2.7200
```

I need a way to split the date ranges, anything greater than or equal to FromDate and less than or equal to ToDate, I need to split them into another column called `IndividualDate` into the same table. Basically, in the given date ranges, if the date exists between the `FromDate` and `ToDate` write the date in another column called `IndividualDate`. For a given `Id`, `DType`, `PType`, `PEnd`, `FromDate`, the `FromDate` and `ToDate` field date ranges do not have duplicates. So, the date ranges are cleanly separated. The final output table(temporary table is fine) for the above sample data would look like this.

```
Id          DType   PType   Period  FromDate    ToDate      Highval IndividualDate
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
000000000G  1       A       2015    2014-11-02  2014-11-04  0.4800  2014-11-02 
000000000G  1       A       2015    2014-11-02  2014-11-04  0.4800  2014-11-03 
000000000G  1       A       2015    2014-11-02  2014-11-04  0.4800  2014-11-04 
000000000G  1       A       2015    2014-11-01  2014-11-01  1.2860  2014-11-01 
000000000G  1       A       2015    2014-10-28  2014-10-31  1.2290  2014-10-28 
000000000G  1       A       2015    2014-10-28  2014-10-31  1.2290  2014-10-29 
000000000G  1       A       2015    2014-10-28  2014-10-31  1.2290  2014-10-30 
000000000G  1       A       2015    2014-10-28  2014-10-31  1.2290  2014-10-31 
000000000K  4       2       2015    2014-12-17  2014-12-20  2.5800  2014-12-17 
000000000K  4       2       2015    2014-12-17  2014-12-20  2.5800  2014-12-18 
000000000K  4       2       2015    2014-12-17  2014-12-20  2.5800  2014-12-19 
000000000K  4       2       2015    2014-12-17  2014-12-20  2.5800  2014-12-20 
000000000K  4       3       2015    2014-12-15  2014-12-16  2.1700  2014-12-15      
000000000K  4       3       2015    2014-12-15  2014-12-16  2.1700  2014-12-16 
000000000K  4       3       2015    2014-11-14  2014-12-14  2.7200  2014-12-14
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I should also mention that the final table would possibly have several million records. So, it needs to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one uses a `Tally Table`. For reference: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

```
;WITH e1(N) AS(
    SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0
)
,e2(N) AS(SELECT 0 FROM e1 a, e1 b)
,e4(N) AS(SELECT 0 FROM e2 a, e2 b)
,Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, FromDate, ToDate) + 1) FROM TableA) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM e4
)
SELECT
    a.Id,
    a.Dtype,
    a.Ptype,
    a.Period,
    FromDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.FromDate, 120),
    ToDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.ToDate, 120),
    IndividualDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, t.N -1, a.FromDate), 120)
FROM TableA a
CROSS JOIN Tally t
WHERE   
    t.N - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, a.FromDate, a.ToDate)
ORDER BY a.Id, a.DType, a.PType, a.Period, a.Highval, IndividualDate
```

Comment: This will scale better than the `recursive CTE`. Read this for reference:http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: Thank you. Due to time constraints to get something going, I solved the issue that I had with another way, thereby, I did not have to deal with the issue that was posted. But, I did try this and it seems to be working. I did try playing with recursive CTE before posting the question and did not have much luck. Thank you for your help! I will study this up to understand better and use in my future work. Thanks again for the time and explanation. Simply awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Recursive CTE` to generate `dates`

```
DECLARE @maxdate DATE

SELECT @maxdate = Max(todate)
FROM   Yourtable;

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Min(fromdate) Invidualdate
         FROM   Yourtable 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(dd, 1, Invidualdate)
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  Invidualdate < @maxdate)
SELECT id,
       DType,
       PType,
       Period,
       FromDate,
       ToDate,
       Highval,
       Invidualdate
FROM   cte a
       JOIN Yourtable b
         ON a.Invidualdate BETWEEN b.FromDate AND b.ToDate 
Option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Or create `calender` table which is a better way

```
create table calender(Individualdate date)

insert into calender values('2001-01-01'),....,('2020-12-31')


SELECT id,
       DType,
       PType,
       Period,
       FromDate,
       ToDate,
       Highval,
       Individualdate
FROM   calender a
       JOIN yourtable b
         ON a.Individualdate BETWEEN b.FromDate AND b.ToDate
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I should have mentioned that I did try recursive CTE and did not too far. Thanks for the calendar suggestions as well. I appreciate the effort put in this to help out. Thank you.