# How to calculate number of days working on tasks if we have many tasks and the date range of each tasks could have overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, overlap

I run into a question during working and I would really appreciate if anyone could give me some ideas.

We have a table which keeps tracking of tasks employee has finished. Table structure as below :

```
EmployeeNum | TaskID |Start Date of task | End Date of task
```

I want to calculate how many days each employee has invested in each task using this table. At first my code looks like this:

```
Select 
   EmployeeNum,TaskID,DateDiff(day,StartDate,EndDate)+1 as PureDay
from
   TaskTable
Group by 
   EmployeeNum,TaskID
```

But then I found a problem that there are overlaps in the date range for each task.

For example, we have `TaskA, TaskB, TaskC` for one employee.

1. TaskA is from 2018-10-01 to 2018-10-05
2. TaskB from 2018-10-02 to 2018-10-07
3. TaskC from 2018-10-09 to 2018-10-10

In this way, the actual working days of this employee should be from 2018-10-01 to 2018-10-07, and then 2018-10-09 to 2018-10-10 which is 9 days. If I calculate date range of each task then add them together then actual working days become 5+6+2=13 days instead of 9.

I'm wandering if there could be any good ways to solve this overlapping problem ? Thank you very much for any ideas!

Comment: The answer to your question depends on whether the business rules dictate whether or not you count the overlap hours only once (or, for that matter, whether other rules apply).  The answer is in your software specifications/requirements, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will count how many working days each employee spent on each task ;

```
SELECT
    EmployeeNum,
    TaskID,
      (DATEDIFF(dd, StartDate, EndDate) + 1)
         -(DATEDIFF(wk, StartDate, EndDate) * 2)
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PureDay
FROM
    TaskTable
GROUP BY
    EmployeeNum,
    TaskID
```

See [this link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/calculatingworkdays/1660/) for on explanation on how this computation works.

Comment: Hi GMB, thank you very much for your reply, but this is not what I mean. My problem is how to get rid of the overlapping date range while calculating calendar days employees are working on tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the date when a task starts, you can use a cumulative sum to assign a group to each record and then simply aggregate by that group (and other information).

The following query should do what you want:

```
with starts as (
      select sm.*,
             (case when exists (select 1
                                from tb_TaskMaster sm2
                                where sm2.EmpID = sm.EmpID and
                                      sm2.StartDate < sm.StartDate and
                                      sm2.EndDate >= sm.StartDate
                               )
                   then 0 else 1
              end) as isstart
      from tb_TaskMaster sm
     )

select EmpID, count(TaskId) as cnt_TaskID, min(StartDate) as StartDate, max(EndDate) as EndDate,
       datediff(Day, min(StartDate), max(EndDate)) + 1 as PureDay
from (select s.*, sum(isstart) over (partition by EmpID order by StartDate) as grp
      from starts s
     ) s
group by EmpID, grp

order by EmpID
```

In this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6311ce41b02530ca95578c29665c07d8), you could find the DDL & DML for my example data and the working of the code.

Comment: Hi Midhun, Thank you very much for your great help! I learnt a lot from your code!! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Im not sure it will work all the way but you can give it a try :)

```
declare @table table (empid int,taskid nvarchar(50),startdate date, enddate date)

insert into @table
values
(1,'TaskA','2018-10-01','2018-10-05'),
(1,'TaskB','2018-10-02','2018-10-07'),
(1,'TaskC','2018-10-09','2018-10-10')


select *,case when comparedate > startdate then datediff(dd,comparedate,enddate) else datediff(dd,startdate,enddate)+1 end  as countofworkingdays from (
Select empid,taskid,startdate,enddate,lag(enddate,1,'1900-01-01') over(partition by empid order by startdate) as CompareDate from @table
)x
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: This is too simplified, switch the end dates of TaskA and B :-)

Comment: @dnoeth what do you mean?

Comment: When the first range is from 10-01 to 10-07 and the second from 10-02 to 10-05 you get a wrong result

Comment: @dnoeth Yes it would. If that happens :) Nobody knows, only Charles does, but youre right.

Comment: @Thomas, Hi Thomas, thank you so much for your help! This might be working, Please let me have a try and I will let you know if we made it~Sorry I'm new to SQL and it took me a really long time to study and respond. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This eliminates overlapping ranges by adjusting the start date based on all previous end dates:

```
with maxEndDates as
 ( -- find the maximum previous end date
   Select empid,taskid,startdate,enddate,
      max(EndDate)
      over (partition by EmpID 
            order by StartDate, EndDate desc
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)  as maxEndDate 
   from TaskTable
 ),
daysPerTask as
 ( -- calculate the difference based on the adjusted start date to eliminate overlaping days
   select *,
      case when maxEndDate >= enddate  then 0                                   -- range already fully covered
           when maxEndDate > startdate then datediff(dd, maxEndDate, enddate)   -- range partially overlapping
           else                             datediff(dd,  startdate, enddate)+1 -- new range 
      end as dayCount 
   from maxEndDates
 )
 -- get the final count
select EmpID, sum(dayCount)
from daysPerTask
group by EmpID;
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=30bbe73dfa7db93a25e1f0b46ce5e730)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for your responding and help. I found a solution during searching in Stackoverflow, the following is it's link:

[T-SQL date range in a table split and add the individual date to the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311809/t-sql-date-range-in-a-table-split-and-add-the-individual-date-to-the-table)

The Tally table suggested by Felix in the above question is a great way to solve my problem since I have millions of records and the real situation is really complicated.

Thank you all again for your help!